# shopify loader is continuously loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, shopify, shopify-app

Blue line loader is continuosly loading in the shopify. Even apply `ShopifyApp.Bar.loadingOff();` in the apps of shopify.

It reaches to 99.X% and does not completing to 100%.

[image]

Here is the code for loading off the spinner loader. Can any one help? Thanks for the comments and posts in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ShopifyApp.ready(function () {
        ShopifyApp.Bar.initialize();
        ShopifyApp.Bar.loadingOff();
    });
</script>
```

Here is the official embedded sdk support

https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/shopify-apps/embedded-app-sdk/methods#shopifyapp-bar-loadingoff

Comment: Are you loading the Shopify app script before that snippet?

Comment: The app is embedded POS, Where should I use this one in the <head></head> I have mentioned in the app on the server

Comment: There is one script tag which is uploaded . Does I need to upload this one also? and one snippet which are added in the themes.

Comment: i think you are loading the script from the wrong layout page of theme

Comment: The app is integrated in the store. the app is embeded and this dashboard is coming from our server. Did you get what I means to say

Comment: https://developer-insta.myshopify.com/admin/apps/instagram_shoppable